# Публикация пакета в npm для браузерного JS

Tags: javascript, npm

Я хочу опубликовать свой пакет на `npm`, но не для NodeJS, а именно для браузерного JS. Если рассматривать тот же jQuery, то можно увидеть, что есть директория `src` и директория `dist`. И так я видел и в других пакетах. Как мне собрать этот `dist` из `src`?

Comment: Не могу утверждать, но скорее всего скомпилировать в Webpack